# Javascript byte array never same as Java byte array

Tags: javascript, java, typescript

I have an image file (could be any image) and I am turning it into a Blob object in Javascript. Now I need to get the byte array of the blob object, so I am doing like this:

```
  public async blobToSignedEightByteArray(blob: Blob): Promise<Int8Array> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = () => {
        const arrayBuffer = reader.result;
        // @ts-ignore
        const byteArray = new Int8Array(arrayBuffer);

        resolve(byteArray);
      };

      reader.onerror = reject;

      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    });
  }
```

After doing that, I decode the byte array to UTF-8 like this:

```
let byteData = await this.blobToSignedEightByteArray(blob);
return new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(byteData); // some result
```

Now when I use the same image file (from which we also created JavaScript Blob object) in a Java method like this:

```
private byte[] getFileBytes(MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            return file.getBytes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

and pass the result to new String(byteData), I get entirely different result.

```
byte[] imageDataInJava = getFileBytes(file);  // file here is MultipartFile object
return new String(imageDataInJava) // returns completely different result than JavaScript code
```

What could possibly be the cause?

Comment: *After doing that, I decode the byte array to UTF-8 like this:* Why would you try to turn image data into text?

Comment: FWIW, you don't need all that bother in `blobToSignedEightByteArray`. You can just use the Blog's [`arrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) method: `const byteArray = new Uint8Array(await blob.arrayBuffer());`

Comment: You're telling `TextDecoder` to **decode** something from UTF-8 that isn't UTF-8 (unless the blob just happens to contain UTF-8 data, which you haven't said it does). Why? That seems like an odd thing to do. if you're trying to just send the data from the client to a Java server, send the blob or the byte array, not text.

Comment: The thing is, eventually I have to compare the two byte arrays. But in Java server side the byteData is turned into String object like this: new String(byteData). And when I looked into what it does, the code used UTF-8 encoding. So I thought I need to do the same in JavaScript

Comment: @Omaja7 it does not make any sense to convert a byte[] into a String unless you are certain that it contains the correct bytes to do so. You might be better off converting the bytes to a hex or base64 String representation.

Comment: Different text encoders, when asked to encode arbitrary bytes as UTF-8 will probably error in different ways. It's not correct to try to encode arbitrary binary data as a string, just to gain some kind of string op convenience. As @f1sh says, you'll need to use a intermediate encoding that can handle arbitrary binary input. Base64 will take less space than hex